# Get Webpack to ignore certain imports and leave it as-is

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using Webpack for files meant to be ran in Node. I don't want to bundle any files in `node_modules`. I just want Webpack to leave them as `require('module')`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `target: 'node'` in your webpack configuration. Although in general you would use `externals` field to exclude some modules from the bundle. For example, [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) uses `externals` to do exactly what you need. It seems a bit stale, but I think you can check the sources and do something like that yourself if you don't want to depend on an unmaintained lib. [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) shows some code that does more or less the same.

Comment: ...and there is even plugin to do that automaticatlly: [per-deps-external-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peer-deps-externals-webpack-plugin). What an amazing world!

Comment: Doesn't `externals` remove `require`s rather than leaving them as-is?

Comment: Not necessarily. By the way, I've come across another lib that does exactly what you want to accomplish (it uses `externals` under the hood). I'll update my answer.